# Calling perl script doesn't work in PHP APACHE

Tags: php, perl, apache2, call

I have server side code that call a perl script, in this way

```
exec("perl /home/horus/Instaladores/variant_effect_predictor/variant_effect_predictor.pl --everything --offline -i ../users/$username/$project/results/remove_duplicated_lines/BED_filtered/qual/StrandBalance/dbSNP/SnpEff/$vcf -o ../users/$username/$project/results/remove_duplicated_lines/BED_filtered/qual/StrandBalance/dbSNP/SnpEff/VEP/$vcf --stats_file ../users/$username/$project/results/remove_duplicated_lines/BED_filtered/qual/StrandBalance/dbSNP/SnpEff/VEP/$vcf.html",$output);
```

I try the same with exec, system and passthru without success.

If i made a echo right before the exec, all the variables are set acordingly

If i copy past the echo result in a Linux console,using the www-data from the folder where the php script is, everything works as expected

I have perl and the variant_effect_predictor.pl script in the sudoers file

www-data ALL=(ALL)NOPASSWD:/usr/bin/perl
www-data ALL=(ALL)NOPASSWD:/home/horus/Instaladores/variant_effect_predictor/variant_effect_predictor.pl

any idea of what is going there? why php is not calling the script?

Answer (score 0):

First step.  See if you can run a hello world perl script from that location.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

print "Hello World\n";
```

If you can get that to work properly, then I suspect the problem are the relative paths you're sending as parameters.  Try setting them to absolute paths and see if that helps.